# Как собрать gradl`ом проект на компьютере без интернета?

Tags: java, windows, gradle

Помогите разобраться !

Стоит такая задача - необходимо собрать проект gradle`ом на компьютере без интернета. При этом конечно же есть другой компьютер с доступом к сети.
Что  я пробовал:
сборку выполнял на компьютере с интернетом следующей командой:

```
gradlew build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=\jdk1.8 -x test -Pprod -PofflineRepositoryRoot=%maven_repository%
```

все собралось.
Но при попытке выполнить тоже самое на компьютере без интернета появляется ошибка :

```
Plugin [id: 'nebula.lint', version: '9.3.2'] was not found in any of the followi
ng sources:
```

Похоже проблема в зависимостях
Тогда я попробовал перенести cahce gradle на компьютер без интернета. Скопировал папке .gradle из папки пользователя. Не помогло :( ошибки появились следующие:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 3 stopped Daemons could not be reus
ed, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'my-service'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download gradle-lint-plugin.jar (com.netflix.nebula:gradle-lint-p
lugin:9.3.2): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download build-info-extractor-gradle.jar (org.jfrog.buildinfo:bui
ld-info-extractor-gradle:4.9.7): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download gradle-git-properties.jar (gradle.plugin.com.gorylenko.g
radle-git-properties:gradle-git-properties:2.2.2): No cached version available f
or offline mode.....
```

При этом если я на компьютере с интернетом запускаю gradle с ключом --offline все проходит хорошо.
Как можно перенести скачанные gradle зависимости на компьютер без интернета ?

Comment: как скачать зависимости с мавен - репозитория, не имея доступ к мавен-репозиторию?)) это скорее риторический вопрос

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436473/build-gradle-repository-for-offline-development

Comment: Спасибо за ответы !.
Доступ у меня есть но с другого ПК. Вопрос в том как перенести их. Каков правильный и лучший способ сделать это ?

Answer (score 0):

Единственное решение которое я нашел:

1. Устанавливаем для gradle переменную GRADLE_USER_HOME=C:\Source\cache
2. Выполняем сборку с подключенным интернетом

   gradlew build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=%project_dir%tools\jdk1.8 -x test -Pprod -PofflineCache=%GRADLE_USER_HOME%
3. В результате в папке GRADLE_USER_HOME появятся зависимости.
4. Копируем все на компьютер без интернета с сохранением путей !
5. Выполняем сборку.